# Android Studios unable to find gradle tasks to build a program

Tags: java, android, kotlin, build.gradle

When I try to build a kotlin program on android studio, it displays the notification:

```
*Unable to find Gradle tasks to build: [:]. 
Build mode: COMPILE_JAVA. 
Tests: All.*
```

This happens when I try to debug or run a code like

```
fun main(){
    println "hello world \n I am Michael Girum."
}
```

Comment: have you found a solution for that? I'm facing the same problem and I'm desperately looking for an answer

Answer (score 1):

As I tried to build an old Android project

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
```

I solved it by adding a

```
settings.gradle
```

with content

```
include ":app"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio, under the project source files, under android>app>src, right click on build.gradle, and click Run 'android'

This will than compile, you can than run the project.

Answer (score 0):

As workaround you can run UnitTest from terminal, see https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line#RunTestsGradle